# MongoDB jsonarray length inside collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have Collection in MongoDB and each document in the collection in below form
`{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "4c6d8"} , "description" : "QUESTION" ,  "names" : [ "A" , "B" , "C" , "D" , "E" ]}`
I want to get the count of names

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(uri);
DB database = mongoClient.getDB(databasename);
DBCollection collection = database.getCollection(tablename);
BasicDBObject whereQuery = new BasicDBObject();
whereQuery.put("description", "QUESTION");
DBCursor cursor = collection.find(whereQuery);
try {
while(cursor.hasNext()) {  
System.out.println(cursor.next())
}
} finally {
cursor.close();
}
```

I dont know how to get the count of names . Expected result -"5"

Answer (score 0):

I am not a Java developer to write Java code but here is the query that works in MongoDB query editor. please plug this query in your code and check it out.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "description": "QUESTION"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      NumberOfItemsInArray: {
        $size: "$names"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**the result**

```
[
  {
    "NumberOfItemsInArray": 5
  }
]
```

Comment: Thank you @JBoneion  . I need this in Java code for my implementation

Comment: @novice I thought you were a Java developer. If no one else answers this question then take this query and post it in Java group asking `how to plug this query in Java`. May be that would get you some answers. Right now, you have only tagged `mongodb` so `java` group wont be able to see it. Change the tag to `java` in your next question if you plan to ask it in `java` group. I tried.